# Is it possible to submit a subdirectory to directories for seo purposes?

Tags: search, optimization, seo

I would like to know is it possible to submit a subdirectory to directories
For example let's say that you have site.com/directory can the subdirectory be submitted to directories. I am about to embark on some seo for a client who wishes her site to rank high in search engines.  I know that one of the ways to accomplish this is to have sites listed in directories such as yahoo for example.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want -- what do you mean "submit"? Or are you using "directory" in two different senses in the same sentence ("folder" and "phonebook")?

Comment: Could you clarify your question or add some examples of what you mean? I'm not clear what you mean by "submit" here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean those spammy "free link for SEO" directories, it will depend entirely on how each directory has been set up.

Also: directories seem a big factor in getting websites a penguin penalty.  I'd avoid them and do proper SEO work if you want to improve your rankings.

Finally, I believe non-code questions should be asked at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ not here.